# Angular - Can't resolve 'querystring' in node_modules webpack 4

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I have Environment with below version's, when I run the application I'm getting *"Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in node_modules webpack"*.

**NodeJs      : 12.22.12 

npm         : 6.14.16 

angular/cli : 9.0.2 

typescript  : 3.7.5 

webpack     : 4.41.6 

Webpack-dev : 3.11.0**

any help/ suggestions.

site opens but no response due to run time error.

Comment: Delete your pacakge-lock.json and node_modules folder and try re-installing node modules again.

Comment: got error after npm update - require node-modules-architect-host.js

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the package manually with:

```
npm install querystring
```